# How to make a Materialize Jumbotron

Tags: css, angularjs, materialize

I am trying to build a sign up page like this one [Sign up page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ0jo.png)

I checked the source code, its using angular material design. So couldn't figure out on how to do this using Matrialize.css itself.
It is similar to a Jumbotron in bootstrap. But I guess its implementation is not as simple as it was in bootstrap.
I suppose that this is done using cards in Materialize. But I am not being able to produce or replicate the same thing. Can anyone shed light on how to use cards properly in Materialize.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have create the simple sign up page with Materialize in below code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sign Up</title>
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!-- icons-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m10">
        <h5>Sign Up </5>
        <div class="card-panel ">
          <h6>Sign up with your email address.</h6>
          <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s8">
              <i class="mdi-communication-email prefix"></i>
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Your email</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s8">
              <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s8">
              <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a href="index.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col "><h6>Create Account</h6></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>        
</body>
</html>
```

and if you want to know more about materliaze you can see [www.materializecss.com/](http://materializecss.com/) link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in React and I've managed to create a Jumbotron using [Card Panel](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) class in Materialize. It does come with a box-shadow which you can remove if you want.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const jumbotronStyle = {
  paddingBottom: '150px',
  boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)"
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-panel grey lighten-2" style={jumbotronStyle}>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Page Title</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```